# Are there any storage optimized Sparse Matrix implementations in C#?

Tags: c#, sparse-matrix

Are there any storage optimized [Sparse Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) implementations in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/).

It has some Spare Matrix [implementations](http://nmath.sourceforge.net/doc/numerics/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Sparse.html). (link is to the old Math.NET site. There is no longer an online version of the documentation).

Comment: This link it NMath is incorrect.  NMath is a math framework from CenterSpace software at www.centerspace.net.

Comment: Wanting to sell your product doesn't mean there aren't other solutions out there. My link is for a FREE OPEN SOURCE project, named NMath!

Comment: Hey Am, why are you yelling?  I'm fine with free open source software or private closed source software - we all use both.  I'm simply pointing out that your NMath link is wrong.  You're linking NMath to the Math.NET open source project, but NMath is a trademark used by the CenterSpace NMath product.  The project you are linking to is called Math.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for high performance sparse matrix implementation check out [NMath](http://www.centerspace.net) from CenterSpace software.

Here's a partial list of functionality cut from [here](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath/) on CenterSpace's website.

- Full-featured structured sparse
  matrix classes, including triangular,
  symmetric, Hermitian, banded,
  tridiagonal, symmetric banded, and
  Hermitian banded.
- Functions for
  converting between general matrices
  and structured sparse matrix types.
- Functions for transposing structured
  sparse matrices, computing inner
  products, and calculating matrix
  norms.
- Classes for factoring
  structured sparse matrices, including
  LU factorization for banded and
  tridiagonal matrices, Bunch-Kaufman
  factorization for symmetric and
  Hermitian matrices, and Cholesky
  decomposition for symmetric and
  Hermitian positive definite matrices.
  Once constructed, matrix
  factorizations can be used to solve
  linear systems and compute
  determinants, inverses, and condition
  numbers.
- General sparse vector and
  matrix classes, and matrix
  factorizations.
- Orthogonal
  decomposition classes for general
  matrices, including QR decomposition
  and singular value decomposition
  (SVD).
- Advanced least squares
  factorization classes for general
  matrices, including Cholesky, QR, and
  SVD.
- LU factorization for general
  matrices, as well as functions for
  solving linear systems, computing
  determinants, inverses, and condition
  numbers.

Paul

Comment: Paul, based on your profile it appears you work for CenterSpace. It's fine to post about your own product, but your connection to CenterSpace should be disclosed.